# Meaning of this expression

Tags: group-theory, notation, elliptic-curves

I found a relation while studying elliptic curves, I could not understand its' meaning. $E[n]$ is a $n$-torsion subgroup then
$E[n]\cong Z/nZ \oplus Z/nZ$, What does this $\oplus$ symbol mean?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a direct sum, i.e. the elements in the products with finitely many non-zero coefficients.

For finite sums this requirement is trivially satisfied, i.e. $G\oplus G = G \times G$